# Logstash Combine two fields of different documents based on another field (without an ID)

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using the latest version of logstash(7.6.2). I am trying to add two fields based on values in an another field. Find below my sample data with fields **TimeStamp**, **Value** and **Event**. Also, find below my desired output.

**Sample Data**

```
18/May/2015:02:05:10 +0000 10 a
18/May/2015:02:05:15 +0000 20 b
18/May/2015:02:05:26 +0000 30 a
18/May/2015:02:05:48 +0000 40 b
18/May/2015:15:05:08 +0000 50 a
18/May/2015:16:05:03 +0000 60 b
```

**Desired Output with extra field**

```
18/May/2015:02:05:10 +0000 10 a
18/May/2015:02:05:15 +0000 20 b 30
18/May/2015:02:05:26 +0000 30 a
18/May/2015:02:05:48 +0000 40 b 70
18/May/2015:15:05:08 +0000 50 a
18/May/2015:16:05:03 +0000 60 b 110
```

What I was trying to do is to add the field **Value** based on **Event** and create a new field for **Event=b**.

**Elapsed filter** does something like this but it finds the difference of timestamps. But, what i want is to add **Value fields** based on **Event tags**. I tried using aggregate but it requires a unique ID. Is there any way to do this without using ID or creating dynamic IDS?

Any help here is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

Used a **Ruby class variable** and used it across the events along with an **If Else** condition.